# RxJava merge with user created Flowable only emit the last Flowable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

When I using Flowable.merge() on two Flowable (a1, a2) which is created by Flowable.create(), it will only have a2 emitted. But when I merge on two Flowable (b1, b2) which is created by Flowable.interval(), it will have b1 and b2 emitted as I expected. So my question is why these two methods (create & interval) result in two different result streams?

Here is a simple demonstration for my question:

```
public class MergeProblem {

    private static FlowableEmitter<Integer> emitter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Flowable<Integer> a = Flowable.create(emitter -> 
            MergeProblem.emitter = emitter, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

        Flowable<String> a1 = a.map(x -> "a1 " + x);
        Flowable<String> a2 = a.map(x -> "a2 " + x);

        Flowable<Long> b = Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Flowable<String> b1 = b.map(x -> "b1 " + x);
        Flowable<String> b2 = b.map(x -> "b2 " + x);

//        Flowable<String> c1 = Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//            .map(x -> "c1 " + x);
//        Flowable<String> c2 = Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//            .map(x -> "c2 " + x);

        Flowable.merge(Arrays.asList(a1, a2, b1, b2/*, c1, c2*/))
           .subscribe(System.out::println);

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                emitter.onNext(counter.getAndIncrement());
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

So the output will be like these:

```
a2 0
a2 1
b1 0
b2 0
b2 1
a2 2
...
```

It has the same problem with Observable either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is this:

```
emitter -> MergeProblem.emitter = emitter
```

There is generally no reason to sneak out the emitter from `create` but you do, and given two different subscribe() calls, the latest one will overwrite `MergeProblem.emitter` and thus you only have last subscriber to talk to.

Looks like you should use `PublishProcessor` instead which will emit a single `onNext` to as many `Subscriber`s as there are.